# Copy feature class to feature class in loop and a list of fields in modelbuilder

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, fields-attributes

I have a several file geodatabase with seven features in it (polygon).
I want to copy them to a new feature in a other empty file geodatabase (instead of deleting the fields...had same problems with that tool)

What I want: 
I just need 20 out of 60 fields and in the new feature in a new order.
I tried to set up this in Modelbuilder, but there a several problems which I don't get.
I will use the iterator for features thats clear. No problem.
Then feature to feature tool. Up to this point is clear to me.
I create a variable with my necessary field names in the order I want them. clear to me.
But what is not clear:

1. How to say take this list every time for each feature for the field map?
2. How to reorder them? like variable-list has it?

Is it possible with model builder or do I need a script for that?
I have around three million polygons in each feature...

---

I see my english expression was not the best. I am german ;-)
I will simple it a bit easier.

One Filegeodatabase contents: 7 features(polygons) and around 3 million attributes and 60 fields. 
And I have 4 of this filegeodatabases...
Each field in each feature is same by name. 
It is a result of many intersection steps.
But for the end product, I just need 20 of this fields in my desired order.
Yes, I agree to you, I can use the tool, but so I have to click 40 times of each to have my new feature but i cannot move the order in the "fieldmap"-window.

The other option what I could do is, to copy the feature first into the new filegeodatabase and delete the unwanted fields, but at the end it is same clicking time which i not have, so it must be working automated or?
In the delete field tool, it brings check boxes, I can select all or unselect all and search through the fields where are my wanted and so i could get it. 
I can do it for one. And i can not recall the tool from the resultslist, because then he reads the list of the feature again, and i can start choosing again...
is this cleared explained?
On searching the net, i didnt find any useful solution. The example-code of delete-tool in the arcgis-help resource i could not get to run...

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to indicate the version of ArcGIS for Desktop that you are using, please?

Comment: Oh, yes I forget it.
I use ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 SP1 with all Extensions(at University).

Comment: Couldn't you just select the fields you want and then export them?

Comment: Clarify. Several with  seven features in it. Seven in each or seven total. You want to copy features to a new features? I ham having a hard time understanding what you want to achieve. It seems to me GISKid has a point.

Comment: @GISKid, since each fc probably has a different database schema using an iterator there is not an easy way to select certain field(s) using ModelBuilder.

Comment: I think this question definitely needs some screenshots to assist or even a screenshot of your model. As it stands I'm having a hard time understanding this question.

Comment: @GISKid: Can I select them with modelbuilder? But then how? I don't know? Give me a hint please :-)

Comment: I will make a screenshot, but I have to what several hours before I can answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

I've had little success in re-ordering fields in model builder, not sure if one can even do that? I had written a bit of python that could create a new table that would create an output table with the fields in a user specified order, the code is below, you could adapt it for your needs.

In this example a table with 4 fields is reordered and stored IN_MEMORY.

```python
inputTable = "ABC" # This is a table loaded into ArcMap
outputTable = "XYZ"

# Get field mappings of Input Table
fieldMappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()
fieldMappings.addTable(inputTable)

# Create an empty FieldMappings Object
newFieldMappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()

# Add fields in desired order. Note field index must be known
newFieldMappings.addFieldMap(fieldMappings.getFieldMap(3))
newFieldMappings.addFieldMap(fieldMappings.getFieldMap(0))
newFieldMappings.addFieldMap(fieldMappings.getFieldMap(2))
newFieldMappings.addFieldMap(fieldMappings.getFieldMap(1))

# Create Table
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(inputTable, "IN_MEMORY", outputTable, None, newFieldMappings)
```